# discordpy2 button interaction.edit_original_response() returning 404 not found (error code :10015)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, discord-buttons

I am attempting to make a menu in a Discord.py bot using buttons in a slash command.

**My code:**

```
    class helpbclass(discord.ui.View):

      def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = None

      @discord.ui.button(label="General",
                         style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple,
                         emoji="")
      async def general(self, interaction: discord.Interaction,
                        button: discord.ui.Button):
                        await interaction.response.edit_original_response('general')

      @discord.ui.button(label="Moderation",
                         style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple,
                         emoji="")
      async def moderation(self, interaction: discord.Interaction,
                           button: discord.ui.Button):
                        await interaction.edit_original_response(content='moderation')

      @discord.ui.button(label="QUIT", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, emoji="")
      async def quit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction,
                     button: discord.ui.Button):
                        await interaction.edit_original_response(content='quit')
                        self.value = False
                        self.stop()


    @client.tree.command(name="test",
                         description="Menu testing",
                         guild=discord.Object(id=123456789))
    async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):
      await interaction.response.defer()
      #code for embed
      view = helpbclass()
      await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed, view=view)
      # i also tried interaction.response.send_message, without the response.defer() at top
```

**The problem**
It returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/AtlaReboot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ui/view.py", line 425, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "main.py", line 61, in moderation
    await interaction.edit_original_response(content='moderation')
  File "/home/runner/AtlaReboot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/interactions.py", line 462, in edit_original_response
    data = await adapter.edit_original_interaction_response(
  File "/home/runner/AtlaReboot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/webhook/async_.py", line 218, in request
    raise NotFound(response, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10015): Unknown Webhook
```

**My question:**
I checked the error code meaning, why does it return a webhook error?
How can I get the original embed I sent in the command output to be edited with another embed when a button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite unfamiliar with the discord wrapper you are using, as it has a rather odd order of callback parameter. I usually see button come before the interaction parameter but anyway try deferring the interaction before doing `edit_original_message` in each callback.

Comment: Thank you! The editing part works after I defer before editing, but it still shows "This interaction failed", what can I do about that?

Comment: I’m not sure, did it raise any error? “The interaction failed” message on discord could mean several things; such as bad connection on your side, or the http request failed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to call:

```
await interaction.response.defer()
```

Answer (score 1):

## **Answer for discord.py by rapptz**

### Method 1

To edit a reply on a interaction, you need to first get the message object of the original response.

```
message = await interaction.original_response()
```

From there you can simply call:

```
await message.edit(content="new message :D")
```

### Method 2

Defering
Simply just call

```
await interaction.response.defer()
```

Then simply just

```
await interaction.edit_original_response(content='new message :D')
```

Cheers, Eric